# MongoDB not inserting data

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new beginner in Node.js and MongoDB and started to implement few POST API. I am using MongoDB to insert data via POST, While testing on terminal its showing that database is created, but while doing POST, showing error that db is not found. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Below is my code

```
const express     = require('express');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const bodyParser  = require('body-parser');

const app         = express();
const port        = 8080;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb"

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('We are live on ' + port);
});

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Database created!");
  db.close();
});

app.post('/api/notes', function(req, res) {

    var myobj = { text: req.body.body, title: req.body.title };
    var dbase = db.db("mydb");
    dbase.collection('notes').insertOne(myobj, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        res.send({ 'error': 'An error has occurred' });
      } else {
        res.send(result.ops[0]);
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: can you attach logs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `db` is not available outside that's why you are getting the error.

Try this way:

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Database created!");
 global.db=db;
//don't close connection here if you want to use outside just put it as global
});
```

You can refer https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/node-mongodb-native/mSGnnuG8C1o/Hiaqvdu1bWoJ for better understanding about MongoDB native connection

Which says:

> You open do `MongoClient.connect` once when your app boots up and reuse the db object. `It's not a singleton connection pool each` .connect creates a `new connection pool`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have closed connection after post, is that right one, or if i need to have mutiple get and post, then where do we need to make connection close

Comment: You no need to close the connection, you can use as it is. See the link which will give you better understanding :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this knowledge with me.

Comment: You can up-vote if you think it's right answer related to connection :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to understand the variable scopes here. the scope of variable `db`is local which means it is not accessible outside the callback of `MongoClient.connect`. `dbase` will be `undefined` if am not wrong.
Try this:

```
 app.post('/api/notes', function(req, res) {
  var myobj = { text: req.body.body, title: req.body.title };
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
   if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send('Db Connection Failed..')
      } else {
        var myobj = { text: req.body.body, title: req.body.title };
        var dbase = db.db("mydb");
        dbase.collection('notes').insertOne(myobj, function(err, result) {
           if (err) {
         res.send({ 'error': 'An error has occurred' });
       } else {
         res.send(result.ops[0]);
       }
        })
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is not right way to create connection. As per your code he has to create connection on every API which is not best practice

Comment: Yeah I knew it but I thought to give a quick fix. Thanks that you gave time for my code i appreciate it.